# How to register Quartz Scheduler with Windsor?

Tags: castle-windsor, quartz.net-2.0

What I have tried so far?

```
container.Register(Component.For<Quartz.IScheduler>()
        .UsingFactoryMethod(() => GetQuartzScheduler())
        .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
```

Inside GetQuartzScheduler()

```
string tcp = string.Format("tcp://DevMachine:8888/QuartzScheduler");
NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = string.Format("MyQuartz_{0}", alias);
// set thread pool info
properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy"] = "true";
properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "0";
properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy.address"] = tcp; //tcp variable is set before

Quartz.ISchedulerFactory sf = new Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
sched = sf.GetScheduler(); //<--**Throws exception**
```

The exception is:

```
Factory method creating instances of component 'Late bound Quartz.IScheduler' returned null. This is not allowed and most likely a bug in the factory method.
```

Any suggestions to correct this?

Comment: Are you sure that's where the exception is thrown?  Is there an inner exception?  Show the complete code for GetQuartzScheduler().

Comment: A scheduler per web request doesn't sound good.

Comment: In case of an exception: always add the stack trace to your question.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: +1. Modified it to Singleton. However, in the future the Singleton may not suit us. I'll post another question about it when the time comes. The error turned out to be silly, I was connecting to a Service instance that was not running.

Comment: @Steven: +1 your suggestion to look at Stack Trace helped. The inner exception was null, so didn't look at that initially. Thanks all and sorry for the delayed response.